# Antialiased lines using jogl on Windows 7 look horrible

Tags: windows, opengl, jogl, antialiasing

My java application uses jogl to create surfaces with an overlaid grid. The lines of the grid are anti-aliased. However, on Windows the anti-aliasing is complete garbage, unless I add a small alpha value to the surface. Here are screen shots of the same scene on all three platforms:

Mac OS X:

[image: Mac OSX]

Ubuntu 11.10:

[image: Ubuntu 11.10]

Windows 7:

[image: Windows]

Windows 7 with alpha=0.01:

[image: Windows with (small) alpha (0.01)]

The basic procedure to create this is as follows:

```
gl.glPushAttrib( GL.GL_ALL_ATTRIB_BITS );
gl.glEnable(GL.GL_POLYGON_OFFSET_FILL);
gl.glPolygonOffset(1.0f, 1.0f); 
drawSurface(gl);
gl.glDisable(GL.GL_POLYGON_OFFSET_FILL);
gl.glPopAttrib();

gl.glDisable( GL.GL_LIGHTING );
gl.glDepthFunc(GL.GL_LEQUAL);
float[] c = {0, 0, 0, 0.5f};
gl.glColor4fv(c, 0);//the alpha here gets overridden if one is specified for the surface (which is why the Windows-with-alpha produces a darker grid)
drawGrid(gl);
gl.glDepthFunc(GL.GL_LESS);
gl.glEnable( GL.GL_LIGHTING );
```

The drawSurface() method also does the following before creating the polygons for the surface (using GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP primitives):

```
gl.glPushAttrib(GL.GL_LIGHTING_BIT);
gl.glColorMaterial(GL.GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL.GL_AMBIENT_AND_DIFFUSE);
gl.glEnable(GL.GL_COLOR_MATERIAL);
```

The drawGrid() method sets up anti-aliasing like so:

```
gl.glEnable(GL.GL_BLEND);
gl.glBlendFunc(GL.GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL.GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
gl.glEnable(GL.GL_LINE_SMOOTH);
gl.glHint(GL.GL_LINE_SMOOTH_HINT, GL.GL_NICEST);
```

The grid itself is created using GL_LINE_STRIPs

I've read up on the [OpenGL documentation regarding line anti-aliasing](http://www.opengl.org/resources/code/samples/sig99/advanced99/notes/node120.html) and also tried out the polygon offset example [here](http://glprogramming.com/red/chapter06.html).

As for hardware, I have dual boot IBM ThinkPad (64-bit quad core) with an integrated nVidia 3100M card and an Intel Core 2 Duo iMac which has an ATI Radeon. Since Ubuntu and Windows are running on the same hardware, I know it can't be a hardware issue.

I'm looking for suggestions for improving the anti-aliasing of the grid lines on Windows.

Comment: Have you tried drawing the lines slightly above the surface? I notice that you switch to `gl.glDepthFunc(GL.GL_LEQUAL)`, but you could still be having z buffering issues due to FP roundoff.

Comment: Also, the OpenGL documentation you linked to suggests disabling **writing** to the depth buffer while drawing the lines, even if you still want to use it to clip them (`glDepthMask_FALSE(GL_FALSE)`).

Comment: @RussellZahniser: I'm using GL_POLYGON_OFFSET_FILL to achieve that.

Comment: @RussellZahniser Yes, I tried setting gl.glDepthMask( false ) - it didn't make any difference.

Comment: The Java mantra: write once, debug everywhere.

Comment: Did you install the drivers downloaded from NVidia's website, or are you using the ones shipping/automatically installed by Windows? If the later, then you should know, that for some obscure reason Mircosoft decided, to remove the perfectly capable OpenGL ICD from the drivers given to them from the HW makers, and substitute them with a rather poor OpenGL-1.4 emulation/implementation translating OpenGL into Direct3D. So my first course of action would be to head over to http://nvidia.com/drivers fetching the most recent one for your GPU and install them.

Comment: Thanks @datenwolf, I'll give that a shot. However, on my desktop machine, which is running an ATI card, I have the exact same problem, so I'm not sure that will help. I'll try it anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out I had not tried (I thought I had, but I did not rebuild and test it correctly)
    gl.glDepthMask( false );

Adding that in correctly did greatly improve the fragmentation of the anti-aliased lines of the grid.

That said, I'm still not 100% happy with the look of the lines, but, for now, this question is resolved. Here is a screen shot of the 'improved' grid lines:

[image]

While this is a great improvement, it's still not as good as Mac OS X or even Ubuntu.